# Entity Framework Cannot Open Database Requested By the Login - The Login Failed For User

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've just uploaded my website to a server and getting an error called "cannot open database requested by the login the login failed login failed for user".

In my global.asax file on Application_Start method, I have this :

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

So I created my database manually and after used script to create tables. But when I want to login, it gives me an error.

On my database my tables, username and password for login page seem fine. Just can't connect to the database.

My connectionstring is:

```
 <add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=serveradress;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'll be grateful for advice.

Comment: Asuming you use MS-SQL: can you connect to the database through the SQL management studio with the given credentials??

Comment: Check if your SQL Server has TCP/IP Communication enabled. I guess problem lies somewhere between EF and Server. Might be firewall as well.

Comment: I can connect via these credentialls on sql management studio. My website files on hosting company.

Comment: Since this issue may originated from connection string, check if your complete connection string adheres with convention here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/.

Answer (score 4):

I've just solved the problem. The problem is "typical programmers problem". I needed to write MyDatabase but I wrote MyDatabse. I'm trying to solve this problem since at 11 o'clock. Thank you for your all replies.

Answer (score 2):

## Connection to database server

You should check if your server can connect to the database server. Perhaps a firewall is blocking the connection.

If the server is using TCP/IP, then the simple way is to just telnet to the SQL Server port and see if it connects. By default, that's port 1433, so this should work:

```
telnet servername 1433
```

That will probably be appropriate in most cases.

If it's using a different port, or dynamic ports (common with a named instance), then you'll need to determine which port it's currently listening on. Check SQL Server configuration manager to see if it's a specific port, or dynamic ports. If it's using dynamic ports, then as long as you don't have multiple instances on the server, `netstat -abn` is probably the simplest way to find what it's using. Otherwise, dig through the Windows event log or the SQL Server error log for a message indicating which port is in use by the instance.

If SQL Server is using Named Pipes, then I believe if you're able to access shares on the machine, you have adequate network connectivity. This article says you can go further and try connecting to the IPC$ share:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275787%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

```
net use \\servername\IPC$
```

## Security settings on database server

Go to SQL Server >> Security >> Logins and right click on "username" and select Properties.

[image: Logins]

In newly opened screen of Login Properties, go to the “User Mapping” tab. Then, on the “User Mapping” tab, select the desired database – especially the database for which this error message is displayed. On the lower screen, check the required role.

[image: User Mapping]

Comment: Couldn't done because It gives permission error. My db on hosting company.

Comment: Is your server able to connect to the database?

Comment: yes I can connect via sql management studio, but when I try to do your way, at the and of the step (click ok button) gives me "you do not have permission Error:15151"